# How to change Device Orientation programmatically in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, orientation

In my app I want to change the device orientation.

I`ve tried it like in the other question with the same topic:

```
let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight.rawValue
UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

But this seems only to work if the orientation is already allowed so that the user can change it with rotating the device, and it also change the orientation with an animation. But I want my app to only have one orientation in VC1 and to have only one orientation in VC2. The user should not have influence on the Orientation, and there should no animation. Is this possible?

Sorry for my bad english....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For each VC declare this variable w/ desired orientation. This is for portrait.

```swift
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask { return .portrait }
```

Then on appearance enforce the desired orientation.

```swift
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewDidAppear(animated)
  UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
  UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
  UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
}
```

Comment: I am glad, I use this everywhere.

Comment: But one Question I still have. How do you design the ViewController in the Storyboard? Because, you can have just one Orientation of ViewController I think...

Comment: I do not know a way from the storyboard to enforce orientation lock. But you could subclass VC and then whatever VC you create on the storyboard will just have to inherit the correct orientation lock.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used this code to successfully fix the orientation for my custom camera :D