# How to restore right orientation of the UIViewController after orientation was forced to landscape by another (iOS)?

Tags: ios, swift, uiinterfaceorientation, interface-orientation

The problem I am having is a bit strange and I can't seem to find any good solutions out there. So I have two UIViewControllers, one is allowed to take all orientations, another can only be viewed in landscape

```
internal override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}

internal override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Lanscape
}
```

If I am in portrait mode on ViewController1, and I push VC2, it rotates just fine, but when I leave VC2, VC1 is stuck in landscape even though device itself is in portrait mode. How can I fix it? I tried calling AttemptToRotateToDeviceOrientation method in ViewDidAppear method of VC1, but it doesn't do anything

Comment: You can check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50936519/how-to-change-device-orientation-programmatically-in-swift/50939184

Comment: @mamun999 you probably misunderstood me. I am not asking how I can force orientation, my solution is working already. I am asking how to fix side-effects of that

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create app delegate instance in your view controller like:

```
let appDel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

On Viewwillappear()of view controller  just add this code for landscape

```
appDel.myOrientation = .landscape
UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
```

And for portrait  add this code

```
appDel.myOrientation = .portrait
UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
```

Comment: It's not quite what I need. I need every controller to have auto rotation to all orientations, but one of them to be only landscape. I get that with my solution but previous controller gets stuck in landscape for some reason

Comment: Alright just do a thing wherever  you need landscape add this code 

`appDel.myOrientation = .landscape
UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")`
And while leaving that screen set the rotation to the every aspect.