# Change The Orientation Of iOS App Programatically

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

How Can I change The Orientation Of My iOS app Programatically when sth Happens Like When I press A Button I need my Device To Go Landscape and in the next time when I click on it return to portrait. I tried this code but nothing happened

```
        let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight.rawValue
        UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

Can Any Body Help Me please !

Answer (score 0):

you can add the following code into an @IBAction or the way you prefer to handle your button press

```
  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
    UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
  }
```

full solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50939184/9065909